# R use reshape to transfer data from wide to long

Tags: r, reshape

My data contains measurement at three time points. There are 2 Groups (placebo and treatment) and each one is assigned an ID. The data looks like

```
Group      ID          Time1         Time2        Time3
1           1          33             44           77
1           2          24             123          54
1           3          32             343          434
1           4          23             23           22
2           5          14             13           24
2           6          67             14           33
2           7          55             34           35
2           6          33             12           11
```

The desired output should be like:

```
Group     ID    Measurement
1         1     33
1         1     44
1         1     77
1         2     24
1         2     123
1         2     54
```

and so on.

How do I transfer to the long form using reshape function? Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  There are two rows having the same `Group` and  `ID` which one would not expect and the output shown does not explain how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `reshape` function you can try this:

```
reshape(df, 
        direction = "long",
        varying = c("Time1", "Time2", "Time3"),
        v.names = "Meassurement",
        idvar = c("Group", "ID"),
        timevar = "Time",
        new.row.names= as.character(1:(nrow(df)*3)))

   Group ID Time Meassurement
1      1  1    1           33
2      1  2    1           24
3      1  3    1           32
4      1  4    1           23
5      2  5    1           14
6      2  6    1           67
7      2  7    1           55
8      2  8    1           33
```

Here is a `tidyverse` way with `pivot_longer`:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("Time"),
               names_to = "Time",
               values_to = "Measurement")

# A tibble: 24 x 4
   Group    ID Time  Measurement
   <int> <int> <chr>       <int>
 1     1     1 Time1          33
 2     1     1 Time2          44
 3     1     1 Time3          77
 4     1     2 Time1          24
 5     1     2 Time2         123
 6     1     2 Time3          54
 7     1     3 Time1          32
 8     1     3 Time2         343
 9     1     3 Time3         434
10     1     4 Time1          23
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R `reshape` solution.

```
vars <- grep("^Time", names(df1), value = TRUE)
Times <- as.integer(sub("[^[:digit:]]*", "", vars))
df1$row.number <- seq_len(nrow(df1))

df2 <- reshape(df1, 
               varying = list(vars), 
               v.names = "Time",
               idvar = c("row.number", "ID", "Group"), 
               times = Times,
               timevar = "Time",
               direction = "long")
df2$row.number <- NULL
row.names(df2) <- NULL

head(df2)
#  Group ID Time
#1     1  1   33
#2     1  2   24
#3     1  3   32
#4     1  4   23
#5     2  5   14
#6     2  6   67
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Group      ID          Time1         Time2        Time3
1           1          33             44           77
1           2          24             123          54
1           3          32             343          434
1           4          23             23           22
2           5          14             13           24
2           6          67             14           33
2           7          55             34           35
2           6          33             12           11
", header = TRUE)
```